# segmentation fault while calling a self-made C function

Tags: c, function, parameters, segmentation-fault

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char* extensionSearch(char * fileName){
    const char* extensions[] = {".exe", ".doc", ".xls", ".ppt", ".txt", ".jpg", ".eml", ".log"};

    char * fName = fileName;
    char* tmpRetValue = "";
    char* finalRetValue = "noExt";
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(extensions)/sizeof(const char *); i ++)
    {
        tmpRetValue = strstr(fName, extensions[i]);
        if(strcmp(tmpRetValue, extensions[i]) == 0)
        {
            finalRetValue = extensions[i];
        }


    }
    return finalRetValue;
}

int main () {
    char* fileExt = extensionSearch("great.exe");
}
```

This is a self-made C function. I am calling it

And it causes a segmentation fault. 
The reason the segment fault occurs is that strstr() returns NULL, But when I read the doc "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm," it never returns NULL. Why does it return NULL?

The function gets a filename and checks whether it has one of those extensions in the function. If it has one, it returns the file extension.

Comment: On which line? (Yes, you should find that out on your own.)

Comment: What is the error and where does it happen?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", *fileName);` is already wrong, `*fileName` returns a `char`, but `%s` expects a `char*`

Comment: As @UnholySheep says. Change to `printf("%s\n", fileName)`

Comment: I am sorry!! I deleted it. I put there for debugging purpose. I made that mistake. 
I feel difficulty setting up gdb over Visual Studio Code with Makefile project. I am sorry I could not point out the exact error point. Windows GDB says that "if(strcmp(tmpRetValue, extensions[i]) == 0)" currently causes a problem.

Comment: `if(strcmp(tmpRetValue, extensions[i]) == 0)` You should be aware that `strstr` will return `NULL` in most cases.

Comment: is there any better way to extract substring out of the whole string, then?

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine. You just need to check the return value before further comparing is done...

Comment: Furthermore, **tutorialspoint** is not **the** documentation. I wouldn't consider using it even as *a* documentation.

Comment: Also, your `const char* extensions[] = {".iexe", ".doc", ".xls", ".ppt", ".txt", ".jpg", ".eml", ".log"};` would need to create a new const array every time. You want `static const char *` here.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Antti Haapala

Comment: You need a better library reference.  For example, CPPReference says "*Return value: Pointer to the first character of the found substring in `str`, or **`NULL` if no such character is found**.*".  (My emphasis)

Comment: I think you should check that for loop, because `sizeof(extensions)/sizeof(const char *)` boils down to `1` on 64 bit platforms and to `2` on 32 bit ones ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the return value of your `strstr` call. If `strstr` returns NULL, you cannot pass that to `strcmp` . You need to do e.g.

```
tmpRetValue = strstr(fName, extensions[i]);
if(tmpRetValue != NULL && strcmp(tmpRetValue, extensions[i]) == 0)
{
       finalRetValue = extensions[i];
}
```

Comment: Why does it return NULL? According to the doc, it never returns NULL.
Read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

Comment: @InchanHwang In the "Return Value" chapter of your link, it says right there: "or a null pointer if the sequence is not present in haystack." So for example, if you call `strstr("Essay.doc", ".exe")` , then strstr returns a NULL pointer, since ".exe" is not found in the "Essay.doc" string.

Comment: Thank you! English is not my 1st language. I sometimes omit details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely here:

```
printf("%s\n", *fileName);
```

The variable `fileName` is a pointer to `char`. Just the type expected when printing a string using the `"%s"` format. However, you dereference the pointer, which result in passing the first character in the string to the `"%s"` format. The expression `*fileName` is the same as `fileName[0]`. It's a single `char` element.

Mismatching format specifier and argument leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is a common cause for crashes like yours.

Comment: I deleted that line.. Thank you for pointing it out